# PowerShell grouping objects and returning the object with the largest ID

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to return all the objects in an array based on the maximum `enrollmentID` for each object in the array. This is what I have so far but it only returns the `enrollmentID` for one object in the array, and I know it's only returning 1 because of the `-First` parameter. I wasn't sure what to put after the `Select-Object`.

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.enrollmentID
} | Group-Object PersonID | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object enrollmentID | Select-Object -First 1
}
```

I have a dataset:

```
enrollmentID,personID,name
15486,2548,Joe
15487,2548,Joe
15234,1648,Fred
```

Expected output:

```
enrollmentID: 15487
personID: 2548
name: Joe
enrollmentID: 15234
personID: 1648
name: Fred
```

Comment: `ForEach-Object {$_.enrollmentID}` effectively expands the `EnrollmentID` property of the input objects, removing all other properties. Remove that step from your pipeline and the code will do what you want.

Comment: I removed the `ForEach-Object {$_.enrollmentID}` and it gave me all the properties for each object but I need it to only return the object with the maximum enrollmentID for Joe plus Fred.

Comment: Your remaining code already does that (sort of), except that you're selecting the lowest ID instead of the highest. Replace `-First` with `-Last` to fix that.

Comment: Ok. I see what I did wrong. But it did not return the object with the larger enrollmentID for Joe. It returned the first one, which was the smaller enrollmentID. How can I make it return the larger enrollmentID? The larger enrollmentID may not always be first or it may not always be second .

Comment: `Sort-Object enrollmentID` sorts the input objects by their `enrollmentID` in ascending order. `Select-Object -Last 1` selects the last object from that sorted list, which is the one with the highest `enrollmentID`. However, the sort order may not be what you expect if `enrollmentID` is not an integer. Please check the data type of that field (`$data[0].enrollmentID.GetType().FullName`).

Comment: What you said about the sorting makes sense. Using `-Last 1` would solve the problem I think but `$data[0].enrollmentID.GetType().FullName` returns Sytem.Object[]. What does that mean?

Comment: What is the type of `$data` and where does it come from?

Comment: `$data` is an array that is populated by querying a SQL table.

Comment: If `$data` were just an array `$data[0].enrollmentID` would not produce an array (`System.Object[]` is an array of PowerShell objects). How exactly do you populate the variable?

Comment: This is how `$data` is set: 
`$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;User Id=$DBUsername;Password=$Password;"
$SQLcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SQLcmd.CommandText = $("select * from dbo.table")
$SQLcmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLcmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$data = $DataSet.Tables[0]`

Comment: Then `$data[0].enrollmentID` should not be an array. Please double-check that you didn't run `$data.enrollmentId.GetType().FullName` by mistake. Also, update your question with the output of `$data[0] | ConvertTo-Json`, so that we can see the structure of the object and the type definition of the field `enrollmentID` in your SQL table. Please avoid posting code incomments, because not only does it become unreadable, it simply breaks, b/c newlines are lost.